# I can't able to push on heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

I have an app on heroku named as  `floating-river-39482` .And I'm trying to deploy the app by giving the command `git push heroku master` .
But I got an error from terminal like this

```
remote: !   No such app as sleepy-inlet-36834.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git/' not found
```

In this error message the name of the app is `sleepy-inlet-36834` .But I'm trying to push the app `floating-river-39482` .
I don't have an app named `sleepy-inlet-36834`.
How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've somehow got your Git repository referencing an old (or deleted) Heroku application.

What you can do most easily is open up your `.git/config` file in your project, and switch out the `https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-inlet-36834.git/` URL with the correct one for your Heroku application: `https://git.heroku.com/floating-river-39482.git`.

Then give it another go =)

To explain further: Heroku works by using Git to setup a 'remote'. Remotes are just places you can push (or pull) code from. Git creates remotes by listing them in your project's `.git/config` file.